# how to capture object in 360/3D view using camera(android SDK)

Tags: android-sdk-tools, panoramas, 360-degrees, 360-virtual-reality, 360-panorama

Hellow Guys,
i need help to capture a object as SBS(Side By Side) in 360  using android SDK, but i haven't fount any SDK in android. but any how some apps are available in playstore. and peoples are using. could somebody help me.!!! Thanks in advances.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to click a 360 degree image from your phone camera?

Comment: no, i mean to create an app to capture 360 degree image in android.

Comment: did you found any working solution ?